# How to stop printing input at 42?

Tags: java

I'm doing a problem on a website where it inputs the numbers:

1
2
88
42
99

and it's supposed to output

1
2
88

The code is supposed to stop printing the input when it hits 42, and it works, but when I submit it to the site, it tells me that it gave the wrong answer.

Here's my code:
http://pastebin.com/y5e8DyHz

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int res;

        for(int i=0;i <5; i++) {
            res = scan.nextInt();
            if (res!=42) {
                System.out.println(res);
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works when I run it in IDEOne, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Thanks!

Comment: So we should just guess which site is asking for this code and waht its requirements are?

Comment: Probably you're just reading 5 inputs and the site expects to read more. I recommend to read the problem one more time and give a better analysis.

Comment: As @LuiggiMendoza suggested, the site is probably running multiple tests (ones with inputs larger than 5), so I would suggest you look at the java [while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop & the scanner 'hasNext' [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: It's very possible that it's due to an extra space or newline. Check what the website says to see.

Comment: what is the error that website reports?

Comment: I agree with @LuiggiMendoza above... you've hardcoded a loop that stops at 5 scans.  Also, your example shows taking 5 numbers as inputs, but your program actually exits as soon as 42 is seen.  If the test being run against your program expects to continue entering numbers, that would cause it to fail as well.  Read the specification more carefully and I think you'll get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you have to use it like shown below, even in your IDE

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int res;

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            res = scan.nextInt();
            if (res != 42) {
                System.out.println(res);
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Reason being what  @jrbeverly mentioned above as his comment

update 1:

If you meant "stop printing the input" as the program must exit on encountering '42',you are good. But if your requirement is just to discard printing the number, and let the program run and accept the next number, then remove System.exit(0) . because System.exit(0) means to terminate the JVM from further execution of the program

update 2:

As @Giovanni Botta mentioned below, the exact solution is provided in the mentioned link, snippet adding here

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
     java.io.BufferedReader r = new java.io.BufferedReader (new java.io.InputStreamReader (System.in));
     String s;
     while (!(s=r.readLine()).startsWith("42")) System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll notice that even this doesn't do the output in the way the OP presented the required format...

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much. I'll accept it as correct when my timer expires.

Comment: yes that's right, format is different, i am putting `println` immediately . So if you need the mentioned format, store in an array and display together

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, you may need to remove the System.exit(0); call.  If the test program expects to be able to continue entering numbers, it will fail.

Comment: @dubstaphone - If you meant "stop printing the input" as the program must exit on encountering '42',you are good. But if your requirement is just to discard printing the number, and let the program run and accept the next number, then remove `System.exit(0)` . because `System.exit(0)` means to terminate the JVM from further execution of the program

Answer (score 2):

Note that a solution to the TEST problem is available in the [SPOJ forums](http://www.spoj.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=37&sid=823014b856cc7987ccf9a336b30bc52d). It's a good example of how to process input as fast as possible in java.